# Non-resolvable parent POM: spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.14.RELEASE

Tags: spring, maven

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.7.14.RELEASE in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached
in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and
'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
am not able to create spring starter project without error

I am using springboot version 2.7.14, maven version 4.0.0. Can someone help me to resolve the problem?

Comment: just use 2.7.14 as a version not 2.7.14.RELEASE